# jquery ajax: new request does not launch after previous is aborted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, abort

In my application, I want to cancel a previous ajax call trigerred by a select change before making a new one.

It does not work : it the previous ajax call is aborted, the new one is not launched.
If there is no previous call aborted, it works fine.

My code :

```
    $('.import-control').on('change', function(){
        if (ajax && ajax.readyState !=4 && typeof ajax==='object') {
            ajax.abort();
        }


        ajax = getPlanningTasks(myroute);

    });

    function getPlanningTasks(route) {
        return $.ajax({
            url:   route,
            type:  'GET',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#json_popup_loader').show();
                $('#tasks-container').html('');
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            $('#tasks-container').html(data);
            $('[name=appbundle_foodanalytics_task_collection] .collection table > thead > tr').show();
        }).always(function(){
            $('#json_popup_loader').hide();
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if (jqXHR.status === 0 || jqXHR.readyState === 0) {
                return;
            }
            $('#tasks-container').html("error");
        });
    }
```

Comment: does it showing any error on console??

Comment: indeed ! I had an ajaxcomplete method somewhere else parsing any ajax response as json. adding atry catch to cope with cases where the response was not in a json format solved it. thanks !

Comment: I have the same issue. After aborting the first ajax call, I'm not able to send another one. It is giving me error message.

Comment: what is your error message ?

Comment: I have not message mate. Just empty alert box.

Comment: It's throwing from ajax error case.